# Workbook opens again when I close it if opened by someone else also

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry about the confusing title. But if a file is opened by someone else, when I open it I get the message that it's opened by someone else and I get the option to open it without being able to save it.
If I choose that option when I close the file it auto opens again.

The file has a few macros that is most likely the cause but I can't understand how it causes this issue.

First of all. The file has an inactivity tracker in a module that runs every five seconds:

```
Private Type LASTINPUTINFO
  cbSize As Long
  dwTime As Long
End Type

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub GetLastInputInfo Lib "User32" (ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO)
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare Sub GetLastInputInfo Lib "User32" (ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO)
#End If

Public tid As Variant
Public lista As Scripting.Dictionary


Function IdleTime() As Single
  Dim a As LASTINPUTINFO
  a.cbSize = LenB(a)
  GetLastInputInfo a
  IdleTime = (GetTickCount - a.dwTime) / 1000
End Function

Sub Form_Timer()

    
    ' lookup the inaktivity time for current user if 0
    If tid = 0 Then
        LR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inaktivitet").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inaktivitet").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        tid = Application.VLookup(UCase(Environ("UserName")), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inaktivitet").Range("B17:G" & LR), 6, False)
        If Not IsError(tid) Then
            tid = tid * 60
        Else
            ' if user does not have a specified inactivity time set the "other" time to user
            tid = Application.VLookup("Övriga", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inaktivitet").Range("B17:G" & LR), 6, False)
            tid = tid * 60
        End If
    End If
    
    
    
    tme = IdleTime
    'Debug.Print tme & " " & Now()
    
    ' display warning when less than 65 seconds
    If tid - tme < 65 Then
        UserForm2.Show vbModeless
        DoEvents
    End If
    
    If tme >= tid Then
        If lista.Exists(UCase(Environ("UserName"))) Then ThisWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Close

    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime RunTime, "Form_Timer", Schedule:=False
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5), "Form_Timer"
End Sub
```

This code is initiated with the workbook_open event below.
The dictionary created is to save the inactivity times (and write permissions) in a dictionary so that it "can't" be manipulated without save permission.

```
Public RunTime

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set lista = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For I = 18 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inaktivitet").Range("B200").End(xlUp).Row
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inaktivitet").Range("B" & I).Value <> "" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inaktivitet").Range("B" & I).Value <> "Övriga" Then
            lista.Add Key:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inaktivitet").Range("B" & I).Value, Item:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inaktivitet").Range("C" & I).Value
        End If
    Next I
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual  ' This is done to make the workbook more responsive due to other event macros
    Form_Timer   ' <----  Here
End Sub
```

And in BeforeSave I make sure the username is in the dictionary, if not they are not allowed to save, and in BeforeClose I turn off the inactivity tracker and set calculation to automatic:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime RunTime, "Form_Timer", Schedule:=False
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error GoTo err
    If Not lista.Exists(UCase(Environ("UserName"))) Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Du har inte behörighet att spara schemat" ' you don't have permissions to save.
         
    End If
    GoTo subend:
    
    
err:
    MsgBox "Något har gått fel, det går inte spara." & vbNewLine & "filen går in i felsäkert läge nu. Kopiera celler/blad som är ändrade till en ny excelfil och spara den." & vbNewLine & "Stäng därefter alla Excelfiler innan du försöker öppna någon Excelfil igen."
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
subend:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

When the user change active workbook the calculation toggles:
But I doubt this is the cause of it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    If Wn.Caption = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Else
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

The rest of the macro running is SheetChange, SheetActivate, and SheetSelectionChange code to color text on the sheets to help the user and display various messages.

What I believe is the issue is that the inactivity timer, that it by some reason runs again after the workbook has been closed and thus open the workbook to do it.
Or do you see something else that cause the workbook to auto open again? It only happens when someone else has the write permissions and I open it no write permissions.
When I close the workbook I get the question if I want to save the changes and I press No.
This should turn off the inactivity timer and then close it, and stop. At least as I see it.

I know that the inactivity timer can be turned off by a skilled person and that the write permission using the dictionary is not 100% safe, but it's not intended to be.

Comment: I think I see the issue now. I did not do as I use to do. The RunTime is not set to the next time the inactivity should run. So when the file closes it tries to unset the next OnTime with a variable RunTime that is not set correctly.

Comment: I think only the line `Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5), "Form_Timer"` may  be the problematic one. Then, inside `Workbook_BeforeClose` event there is `Application.OnTime RunTime, "Form_Timer", Schedule:=False`, which looks to not be run. Why do you have `On Error Resume Next` above the line un-scheduling `OnTime`? In fact, is `Workbook_Open` event triggered?

Comment: Does it ask for saving (before you try closing it)? If yes, in `Workbook_BeforeSave` it is an error handler there. Does it show the message after `err:`? If yes, there is a line there ('Application.EnableEvents = False`), not letting `Workbook_BeforeClose` to be triggered.

Comment: I found the issue. I just had to wait for the file to be available to test my theory . But yes that line is the issue. It should set RunTime first then call `Application.OnTime RunTime` because that saves the next runtime, which means I can also unset it. The reason for the on error resume next if runtime is set to a time in the past it will cause an error, meaning if BeforeClose is called just as runtime was supposed to run it could case an error.

Comment: I supposed that, but I would suggest to test this aspect (to place in a `Public` variable `Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)` when `Application.OnTime` is called and run the necessary `Application.OnTime RunTime, "Form_Timer", Schedule:=False` only if the actual time is not bigger than the one used to schedule the running time. `On error Resume Next` does not let any other `Sub`/`Function` raising an error, if the case and you need to know about it...

Comment: I can see now, that you already had/declared such a variable...

Comment: My observations with Application.OnTime is that it's far better to run the `Schedule:= False` than looking at the variable. It has happened multiple times that Excel Runs the code several times as it did in this file when it restarted itself: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnOGi.png This will clear all three instances of the OnTime and make sure it only runs once in the next iteration. But this is just my observations.

Comment: I am not sure I am able to get you... What I can see in the picture (in my opinion) only proves that you moved the cursor and the idle time has been reset. In such cases the `Sub` executing duration is bigger than 5 seconds an no any other `OnTime` call can be done. So, you can simple comment the lines `On Error Resume Next` and `Application.OnTime RunTime, "Form_Timer", Schedule:=False` **in `Form_Time` Sub**. I was suggested to use `If RunTime > Now Then Application.OnTime RunTime, "Form_Timer", Schedule:=False`, in **`Workbook_BeforeClose` event** and comment `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: Is it something obvious I missed?

Comment: The debug line prints Now(). And as you can see it's printed three times in one second which means the sub is called three times, meaning the workbook has been auto opened three times (due to my incorrect code). In this sub it doesn't do much harm but in other subs having the code run more often than it should could cause issues. If I would do as you suggest it would keep running three instances of the sub every five seconds.

Comment: If the Immediate Window you show in picture is populated by the code  line `Debug.Print tme & " " & Now()`, this only means that the sub is called from somewhere else, I am afraid. It is not anything in the code we can see to do that... I created a test workbook and never happened to see the same time returned by `Now`.

Comment: It's not called from anywhere else. This is caused when the workbook closes and the Application.OnTime runs the sub again, this means it runs the code, and the workbook open also runs it. That means two instances of the same sub runs at the same time. Close the workbook again and it will reopen itself again, and workbook open calls it again, and now we have three instances of the code running.

Comment: I cannot imagine how a workbook can be open at the same second, even using a NASA computer.  I cannot see where in the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event the ` Application.OnTime` is called "to run again". On contrarious, it is cancelled. But my imagination is not infinite, indeed... I tested the code in the way I suggested and **nothing wrong happens**.

Comment: You're not gasping the situation. The workbook opens because of the application on time, when it opens the workbook open runs also, so naturally it will be on the same second, anything else would not make sense. And no, yet again.. the on time fails to cancel since the variable does not have the correct time since the variable is not updated in the sub. I can't explain this any more detailed. The reason your workbook is not set up the same (incorrect) way as mine was.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that RunTime variable is not updated in the inactivity timer.
I missed that part.

The current inactivity (sub Form_timer()) code ends with:

```
    If tme >= tid Then
        If lista.Exists(UCase(Environ("UserName"))) Then ThisWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Close

    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime RunTime, "Form_Timer", Schedule:=False
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5), "Form_Timer"
End Sub
```

It should have been:

```
    If tme >= tid Then
        If lista.Exists(UCase(Environ("UserName"))) Then ThisWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Close

    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime RunTime, "Form_Timer", Schedule:=False
    RunTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
    Application.OnTime RunTime, "Form_Timer"
End Sub
```

This now makes sure I have RunTime set correctly so that it can be canceled with the BeforeSave event.